# Using zipped collections to initialize a case class in scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have to generate a collection of object from some collections of primitive types. So I tried the following two methods and both work:

```
case class Gr (x:Int,y:Int, z:Int)

val x = List(1,2,4,2,5)
val y = Array(1,2,7,4,5)
val z = Seq(1,2,4,8,5)


(x,y,z).zipped.toList.map(a => Gr(a._1,a._2,a._3))
(x,y,z).zipped.map(Gr:(Int,Int,Int) => Gr)
```

So, which one is better and how does the second one actually work ? And is there a better way ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 1st one can be reduced to `(x,y,z).zipped.toList.map(Gr.tupled)` and 2nd can be reduced to `(x,y,z).zipped.map(Gr)`, which seems to be shorter/clearer to me.

---

Recall that the argument to `map()` is, essentially, `A => B`, so instead of writing `ds.map(d => Math.sqrt(d))`, which is type `Double => Double`, we can simply write `ds.map(Math.sqrt)` because `sqrt()` is the correct type.

In this case, the `Gr` constructor is type `(A,A,A) => B`.  The Scala compiler is able to take the output of `zipped` and match the constructor type, so the constructor can be used as the argument to `map()`.

Comment: Both pass all my tests (IDE and REPL). [Scala 2.11.8]

Comment: Yes both work, I had changed the definition of Gr in my code. Didn't notice that. But still how does the second work actually work ?
What kind of implicit conversion is done by Scala here ?

Comment: can you explain what `Gr:(Int,Int,Int) => Gr` is? I can understand `map(Gr)`, but this is weird.

Comment: @Łukasz, yeah, that threw me as well and, no, I can't explain it.

Comment: ok, I think I know what this is. it is just `Gr.apply` with type annotation. `Gr` is the object and `(Int,Int,Int) => Gr` is the type.